# JavaScript RegEx Replace With Wildcard Characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, wildcard

I need to replace part of a string, but I don't know every character that needs to be replaced. For example, I have a string like this:

```
'<text align="left" fontSize="123" color="#000000">'
```

I need to replace whatever value is between the quotes after fontSize. This value could be "123", "12", "0", "xyz", or anything really.

I know it is something like this, but I don't fully understand:

```
var string = '<text align="left" fontSize="999" color="#000000">',
  newSize = 18;
string = string.replace(/fontSize="(.*)"/g, 'fontSize="' + newSize + '"');
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want an explanation of the current or a solution to your problem?

Comment: A solution to the problem, preferably. An explanation of the current would also be helpful. It seems like my current approach is replacing everything between fontSize and the " after #000000.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bM6oN1/1 this is probably what you want, your first regex will match all to the end of line...

Comment: How about `document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].setAttribute("fontsize",newsize)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is greedy, that is it will consume as many characters as it can to satisfy the expression, what you want is a non greedy expression which will stop at the first occurrence of `"`

```
/fontSize="(.*?)"/g
```

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

this expression will also work

```
string = string.replace(/fontSize=.* /, ' fontSize="' + newSize + '"');
```